# Do I need to transform this data for linear regression? If yes, what type of transformation is best?

Tags: regression, linear

[image]

The picture below is the dependent variable on the Y and one of the IVs on the X axis.  The Dependent variable is range bound between .5 and 12 while the IVs range from 0-over a million depending on the IV.  When log base 10 transformed the Q-Q plot is very slightly right skewed compared to the non-transformed data that is very heavily right skewed.  The dataset is around 250,000 data points and I am looking to ensure linearity requirement is met in order to perform linear regression.

Thanks,

Comment: For one thing, you might want to consider how to tackle the apparent heteroschedasticity.

Comment: Just looking at the plot, it doesn't appear linear or log-linear. It is difficult to get a sense of the density of points. Changing the transparency would help some, but also including histograms or a contour plot of the joint density might help show if there is an apparent function between these two variables.

Comment: Your question is phrased with a commitment to linear regression, but I'm unsure that linear regression should be used for this data. What is the question you're trying to answer about the data generating process?

Comment: Galen....I appreciate the comments and agree that I have entered into this analysis assuming linear regression is best.  That might be an incorrect assumption.  The question I would like to answer "Does company count influence CMS-HCC? "  More broadly do specific IVs impact the DV while controlling for a few variables?

Comment: Would a box-cox transformation be appropriate for the heteroschedasticity issue?

Comment: In a sense the heteroschedastic hcc across company count is a sort of 'influence', but I would caution you to avoid thinking that increasing company count causes lower variance in hcc.

Comment: If you are looking for a fairly general approach for estimating association, you could calculate the mutual information. You can estimate a p value for the mutual information using a permutation test procedure.

Comment: I recommend reading in the literature on the variables you have. Sometimes modeling approaches already exist for your given problem.

Comment: You could try Box Cox. It might help.

Comment: Since you have a large sample size, you have lots of options for training parametric models. Perhaps even Bayesian networks for causal inference, if that is the direction you want to go.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed your comment
*""Does company count influence CMS-HCC? " More broadly do specific IVs impact the DV while controlling for a few variables?".*

Assuming you want to use linear regression, the normality assumption should hold for the residuals under the regression model. That is after controlling for relevant variables.

To get help in R, and further explanation, see here
http://r-statistics.co/Assumptions-of-Linear-Regression.html

I hope this might help you to get further with your problem.